# 'pip install` Gives Error on Some Packages but not others

Tags: python, pandas, pip

when i use pip install to install some packages it works fine such as (request and selectolax) but on others such as pandas and other packages i get this output in my terminal:

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [69 lines of output]
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [36 lines of output]
        Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
          Using cached ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
          Installing build dependencies: started
          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
        Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
          Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
          Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
          error: subprocess-exited-with-error

          Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
          exit code: 1

          [13 lines of output]
          C:\Users\rudyr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-envg_xup\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not support describe output
            warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
          C:\Users\rudyr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-envg_xup\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)        
            warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "C:\Users\rudyr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-envg_xup\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
              cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
            File "C:\Users\rudyr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-envg_xup\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
              self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
            File "C:\Users\rudyr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-envg_xup\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
              raise SKBuildError(msg) from err

          Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
          [end of output]

          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
          ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
        Failed to build ninja
        ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1

      See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

it says that the error lies with Cmake but i get similar errors if i try and update cmake, ive also tried with different version of python as the interpreter path.

Comment: Looks like you're missing some build dependencies, cmake is mentioned, maybe gcc isn't installed. Which OS are you using?

Comment: im using windows 11, when i try to install cmake i get a whole set of different errors

Comment: The first thing to fix is the CMake installation. The pip error message states "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build." Please provide the command used to install CMake as well as the error output.